# I can not connect an external button to my Homekit system (ESP8266 without homebridge)

Tags: arduino, iot, esp8266, homekit

After watching this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBj8OLig8Kg
Which is how to create a homekit system without having to use a brigde I wanted to create my own.

My idea is to have 2 different lights that are connected to the internet and I handle them with siri and 2 external buttons that can turn off the light without having to always use siri. (for example if my cell phone runs out of battery). All this in the same ESP 8266.

I could already operate the two lights without the need of a homebridge with the following code

```
#define Relay1    16    //D0
#define Relay2    5     //D1

#define button1   14    //D5
#define button2   12    //D6    
#define button3   13    //D7

bool state1 = false;
bool state2 = false;


// ----------------------------------------------------   Inicializacion de wifi  -------------------------------------------------

static void wifi_init() {
    struct sdk_station_config wifi_config = {
        .ssid = WIFI_SSID,
        .password = WIFI_PASSWORD,
    };

    sdk_wifi_set_opmode(STATION_MODE);
    sdk_wifi_station_set_config(&wifi_config);
    sdk_wifi_station_connect();
}

// --------------------------------------------------------   Logica de Relay1   -----------------------------------------------------

void relay1_write(bool on) {
    gpio_write(Relay1, on ? 1 : 0);
}


void relay1_init() {
    gpio_enable(Relay1, GPIO_OUTPUT);
    relay1_write(state1);
}


void relay1_identify_task(void *_args) {
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++) {
            relay1_write(true);
            vTaskDelay(100 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
            relay1_write(false);
            vTaskDelay(100 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        }

        vTaskDelay(250 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }

    relay1_write(state1);
    vTaskDelete(NULL);
}


void relay1_identify(homekit_value_t _value) {
    printf("Relay 1 identify\n");
    xTaskCreate(relay1_identify_task, "Relay Identify", 128, NULL, 2, NULL);
}


homekit_value_t relay1_on_get() {
    return HOMEKIT_BOOL(state1);
}


void relay1_on_set(homekit_value_t value) {
    if (value.format != homekit_format_bool) {
        printf("Invalid value format: %d\n", value.format);
        return;
    }

    state1 = value.bool_value;
    relay1_write(state1);
}


// --------------------------------------------------------   Logica de Relay2   -----------------------------------------------------

void relay2_write(bool on) {
    gpio_write(Relay2, on ? 1 : 0);
}


void relay2_init() {
    gpio_enable(Relay2, GPIO_OUTPUT);
    relay2_write(state2);
}


void relay2_identify_task(void *_args) {
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++) {
            relay2_write(true);
            vTaskDelay(100 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
            relay2_write(false);
            vTaskDelay(100 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        }

        vTaskDelay(250 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }

    relay2_write(state2);
    vTaskDelete(NULL);
}


void relay2_identify(homekit_value_t _value) {
    printf("Relay 2 identify\n");
    xTaskCreate(relay2_identify_task, "Relay Identify", 128, NULL, 2, NULL);
}


homekit_value_t relay2_on_get() {
    return HOMEKIT_BOOL(state2);
}


void relay2_on_set(homekit_value_t value) {
    if (value.format != homekit_format_bool) {
        printf("Invalid value format: %d\n", value.format);
        return;
    }

    state2 = value.bool_value;
    relay2_write(state2);
}


// ------------------------------------------------   Configuracion del server de Homekit   ------------------------------------------

homekit_accessory_t *accessories[] = {
    HOMEKIT_ACCESSORY(.id=1, .category=homekit_accessory_category_lightbulb, .services=(homekit_service_t*[]){
        HOMEKIT_SERVICE(ACCESSORY_INFORMATION, .characteristics=(homekit_characteristic_t*[]){
            HOMEKIT_CHARACTERISTIC(NAME, "Cuarto"),
            HOMEKIT_CHARACTERISTIC(MANUFACTURER, "Estonian Port"),
            HOMEKIT_CHARACTERISTIC(SERIAL_NUMBER, "ASD123"),
            HOMEKIT_CHARACTERISTIC(MODEL, "C.U.C.A"),
            HOMEKIT_CHARACTERISTIC(FIRMWARE_REVISION, "0.1"),
            HOMEKIT_CHARACTERISTIC(IDENTIFY, relay1_identify),
            NULL
        }),
        HOMEKIT_SERVICE(LIGHTBULB, .primary=true, .characteristics=(homekit_characteristic_t*[]){
            HOMEKIT_CHARACTERISTIC(NAME, "Luz"),
            HOMEKIT_CHARACTERISTIC(ON, false,
            .getter=relay1_on_get,
            .setter=relay1_on_set
            ),
            NULL
        }),
        NULL
    }),
    HOMEKIT_ACCESSORY(.id=2, .category=homekit_accessory_category_lightbulb, .services=(homekit_service_t*[]){
        HOMEKIT_SERVICE(ACCESSORY_INFORMATION, .characteristics=(homekit_characteristic_t*[]){
            HOMEKIT_CHARACTERISTIC(NAME, "Cuarto"),
            HOMEKIT_CHARACTERISTIC(MANUFACTURER, "Estonian Port"),
            HOMEKIT_CHARACTERISTIC(SERIAL_NUMBER, "ASD123"),
            HOMEKIT_CHARACTERISTIC(MODEL, "C.U.C.A"),
            HOMEKIT_CHARACTERISTIC(FIRMWARE_REVISION, "0.1"),
            HOMEKIT_CHARACTERISTIC(IDENTIFY, relay2_identify),
            NULL
        }),
        HOMEKIT_SERVICE(LIGHTBULB, .primary=true, .characteristics=(homekit_characteristic_t*[]){
            HOMEKIT_CHARACTERISTIC(NAME, "Luz"),
            HOMEKIT_CHARACTERISTIC(ON, false,
            .getter=relay2_on_get,
            .setter=relay2_on_set
            ),
            NULL
        }),
        NULL
    }),

    NULL
};


homekit_server_config_t config = {
    .accessories = accessories,
    .password = "111-11-111"
};


// -----------------------------------------------------------   MAIN   ----------------------------------------------------------

void user_init(void) {
    uart_set_baud(0, 115200);

    wifi_init();
    relay1_init();
    relay2_init();
    homekit_server_init(&config);
}
```

but i cant figure out how to implemet the two external buttons. I tried implementing:

```
void setup()
{
  pinMode(button1, INPUT);   
  pinMode(button2, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
    if (digitalRead(button1))
    {
     relay1_write(state1);
    }
}
```

but it gives me error, since, I have no way to implement the library .
I also try to understand this example. 
https://github.com/maximkulkin/esp-homekit-demo/tree/master/examples/button
but it does not apply to what I want to do since in that case because the button is recognized by homekit and I want it to just turn off and turn on the light

Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more appropriate for [arduino.se]. In addition, it's unsuitable for this site because *it gives me error* is not a useful or meaningful problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While writing my question I realized something and after thinking it better I think I should connect the relay of the output to a combined light key.  in that way it would give the possibility of turning the light on and off in an analogical way.  Sorry for the inconvenience!  thank you